# find whether the string starts and ends with the same word

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to check whether the string starts and ends with the same word. eg`earth`.

```
s=raw_input();
m=re.search(r"^(earth).*(earth)$",s)
if m is not None:
    print "found"
```

**my problem is when the string consists only of one word** eg: `earth`

At present I have hard coded this case by

```
if m is not None or s=='earth':
    print "found"
```

Is there any other way to do this?

EDIT:

words in a string are separated by spaces. looking for a regex solution

`some examples`:

"earth is earth" ,"earth", --> `valid`

"earthearth", "eartheeearth", "earth earth mars" --> `invalid`

Comment: are you looking for a specific word (`earth`) or any other random word

Comment: it can be any word. preferrably a solution with regular expression but other simple solutions are also welcome :)

Comment: Wait, do you mean (1) when you run this code, you'll know what word you're looking for, and you want to check that the string both begins and ends with that specific word, or (2) there's no specific word, you just want to see if the first and last words in the string are the same, whatever that word may be?

Comment: What about something like `eabce`? it starts and ends with the same letter `e`.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, i mean (2) there's no specific word i am looking for. used the word 'earth' for example

Comment: @Ajax add some better examples.

Comment: When you say "word", what separates the words, or are you just talking about characters? In other words (sorry about the pun), clearly the string "foo bar foo" should return true, yes? But what about the string "foobar foo"? Should that return true or not?

Comment: @MichaelGeary letters make word..so letters !=word

Comment: Since what you really want is, if a sentence starts and ends with the same word - you first have to define what is a _word_. Simply using `\w`, which `matches any alphanumeric character and the underscore; this is equivalent to the set [a-zA-Z0-9_]` won't work because most of your sentences will fail this check; as hardly any will start and end with a preposition.

For example, consider this sentence, should this match? `The Earth is not completely round, just like other planets that look like Earth.`

Comment: @Ajax if `"earth"` is valid then `"earthearth"` should also be valid. Specify your requirements clearly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use backreference within regex

```
^(\w+\b)(.*\b\1$|$)
```

This would match a string only if it

- starts and ends with the **same** word
- has a single word

Comment: Right, but using regex in general for this case seems like an overkill :)

Comment: @mishik his question is `find whether the string starts and ends with the same word`.. i guess he wants to match a string with any word not only `earth`

Comment: `ends with the same word- 'earth'.` :)

Comment: @mishik he says  **eg: earth**..so it can be any word

Comment: @Anirudh, your quote is a misquote...you can't just chop off the end of a sentence to change it's meaning.

Comment: @Anirudh, That's two misquotes.  Wanna go for a 3rd?

Comment: that is something we should clarify with op

Comment: i am working on my regex skills so was looking for a regular expression as an answer. :)

Comment: @7stud hope that comment of op helps..he needs 2nd option..:P

Comment: @Ajax i guess the above regex is what you are looking for :P

Comment: @Anirudh: correct me if wrong - first you check for a single word then check if second part is blank by `|$` or first word matches with last using `\1$` . 
why doesn't this work: r"^(\w+\b).*(\b\1$|$)" ?

Answer (score 7):

Use the [`str.startswith`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) and [`str.endswith`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith) methods instead.

```
>>> 'earth'.startswith('earth')
True
>>> 'earth'.endswith('earth')
True
```

You can simply combine them into a single function:

```
def startsandendswith(main_str):
    return main_str.startswith(check_str) and main_str.endswith(check_str)
```

And now we can call it:

```
>>> startsandendswith('earth', 'earth')
True
```

---

If, however, if the code matches words and not part of a word, it might be simpler to split the string, and then check if the first and last word are the string you want to check for:

```
def startsandendswith(main_str, check_str):
    if not main_str:  # guard against empty strings
        return False
    words = main_str.split(' ')  # use main_str.split() to split on any whitespace
    return words[0] == words[-1] == check_str
```

Running it:

```
>>> startsandendswith('earth', 'earth')
True
>>> startsandendswith('earth is earth', 'earth')
True
>>> startsandendswith('earthis earth', 'earth')
False
```

Comment: @Anirudh could you explain? The OP hasn't explicitly said anything about words having to be separated (and the OP's regex didn't deal with it either).

Comment: check out the comments in question

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`str.startswith`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) and [`str.endswith`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith):

```
>>> strs = "earthfooearth"
>>> strs.startswith('earth') and strs.endswith("earth")
True
>>> strs = "earth"
>>> strs.startswith('earth') and strs.endswith("earth")
True
```

**Update:**

If the words are separated by spaces and the start and end string is not known then use [`str.split`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) and [`str.rsplit`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit):

```
>>> strs = "foo bar foo"
>>> strs.split(None, 1)[0] == strs.rsplit(None, 1)[-1]
True
# single word
>>> strs = "foo"
>>> strs.split(None, 1)[0] == strs.rsplit(None, 1)[-1]
True
>>> strs = "foo bar ffoo"
>>> strs.split(None, 1)[0] == strs.rsplit(None, 1)[-1]
False
```

Comment: +1 for the more efficient `split(None, 1)` and `rsplit(None, 1)` not mentioned by many other `split`-based answers. Your initial code would have been a slightly better example if it followed PEP 8, though. :)

Comment: @downvoter care to explain your downvote so that I can improve my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here:

```
X = words.split()
X[:1] == X[-1:]
```

The slicing makes it work for empty strings too, and extend nicely to any number of words. If `words` cannot be empty, use

```
X[0] == X[-1]
```

Comment: Simple, but less efficient than using `split(None, 1)` and `rsplit(None, 1)`.

Comment: True. But efficiency was not an explicit requirement, so IMHO simpler is better.

Comment: It really depends on the context: if I see `X = words.split()` at the beginning of a longer function, it tells me that I must remember that all the words are important and will probably be used. If the two lines you write are the last ones in a function and the function is not called repeatedly, then OK.

Comment: @EOL there's always `del X` ... (Yeah, I'm not serious. I see your point)

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you absolutely want regex, you can make use of lookarounds, since they don't consume characters.

```
>>>import re
>>>s1 = 'earth is earth'
>>>s2 = 'earth'
>>>m = re.search(r"^(?=(earth)).*(earth)$",s1)
>>>m.group(1)
'earth'
>>>m.group(2)
'earth'
>>>m = re.search(r"^(?=(earth)).*(earth)$",s2)
>>>m.group(1)
'earth'
>>>m.group(2)
'earth'
```

For any string, you could perhaps use this:

```
^(?=([A-Za-z]+)).*(\1)$
```

I'm assuming words as being only alphabet characters. If you mean words as in non-space characters, then you may go for `\S` instead of `[A-Za-z]`.

EDIT: Okay, it seems there's more to it. What I think might suit is:

```
^(?=(earth\b)).*((?:^|\s)\1)$
```

For the work earth. For any word stored in a variable named `word`;

```
>>> word = 'earth' # Makes it so you can change it anytime
>>> pattern = re.compile('^(?=(' + word + '\b)).*((?:^|\s)\1)$')
>>> m.search(pattern, s)
```

Accepts:

```
earth is earth
earth
```

Rejects:

```
earthearth
eartheearth
earthis earth
```

And after that extract the captured groups or check whether the group are empty or not.

The bit I added is `(?:^|\s)` which checks for whether the word you're looking for is the only one in the 'sentence' or whether the word is in a sentence.